# Javascript google maps marker category

Tags: jquery, google-maps

This is inside the google initialize function and works fine. It's the code below which loops through the markers which is getting `marker[i] is undefined`

```
$.each(places, function(index, value) {
    x++;
    var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(value[1], value[2]);
    var icon = value[3];

    if(value[3] == 'HI') icon = "NF";
    if(value[3] == '') icon = "WH";

    marker[x] = new google.maps.Marker({     
        position: pos,
        map:map,
        title: value[0],
        shadow: shadow,
        icon: "../img/markers/" + icon + ".png"
    });

    marker[x].locType = icon;
});
```

Here's the loop outside the initialize function - Getting `marker[i] is undefined`, doing an `alert(marker)` gives me `[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]` etc....

```
$(".team").click(function() {
    var type = $(this).attr("id");
    $.each(marker, function(i, val) {
        if(marker[i].locType == type) marker[i].setVisible(false);
    })
});
```

Comment: Is there any difference in usage of `x` and `index`?

Comment: Why are you using a jquery each loop and then increment a `x` variable yourself? First you could just use the `index` variable that gets passed to the function. Even better would be using a regular `for` loop though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the

```
x++;
```

this probably indicates that your array start at index `1` instead of `0`

so you result probably is:

```
[1] = Object
[2] = Object
etc.
```

when running the `$.each` method it tries

```
marker[0].locType
```

Solution is to move the `x++` to the end of the `$.each(places, function(index, value) {`

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the array?

```
var marker = Array();
```

Comment: Sorry yes, it's set outside the initialize function and returns [object][object],[object][object] etc....when I debug it